# cant do "GET" xmlhttrequest - error

Tags: javascript, xml, get, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

```
  function regist(nome,pwd){
        URL+="register?nick=" + nome + "&key=" + pwd;
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("get", URL, true);//Assincrono

        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (req.readyState != 4) { 
                return;
            }
            else if (req.status != 200) {// Tratamento de erro (e.g., mostrar mensagem de erro)
                return;
            }
            var data=JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                    alert(data);
            if(data.error==null || data.error==undefined){
                    document.getElementById("register").innerHTML="Registo Bem Sucedido";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("register").innerHTML="Utilizador já registado - Password errada";
                }
        };
        req.send();
    };
```

I CANT ACCESS at var data.. Maybe because "*req.onreadystatechange = function(){-----" 
What's appening? My alert to data isn't working, it was not readed.. Can you help me?>the URL is correctly defined, don't worry ;)

---

I don't know nothing about same origin policy problem... 
The URL used in GET is: dcc.fc.up.pt:8080/TabuWeb/rest/register?nick=ola&key=mundo
My page URL: file:///home/carlos/public_html/TabuWeb2/WebContent/index.html?nick=ola&key=mund‌​o

Is there any problem about same origin policy??That's Why my req.status=0 and firebug is pointig to req.send()?

Thanks

Comment: What content does `alert(data)` show? Or does it throw an exception before it gets there? What, specifically, happens when this code is run?

Comment: Use `return console.log(req.readyState, req.status);` where your `return;`s are and instead of the `alert`, and you'll be able to follow every step of the request. (You may find it never reaches 200 OK). You also say `URL` is correctly defined but I'll point out that [`window.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL) exists so if you're `+=`ing it, you'll end up with weird results.

Comment: Well, I got 0 after doing an alert(req.status): So, why req.status=0? I discovered other thing, i started a console.log(req), and I got "GET:"URL" (LOADING)" pointing to server.js(line 52) (req.send(null)). If I do "resend", the response is shown by FIREBUG.. Well, I get this after doing an alert(req.status): else if (req.status != 200){ alert(req.status) ------>>>>>0 return;} So, why req.status=0? I discovered other thing, i started a console.log(req), and I got "GET:"URL" (LOADING)" pointing to server.js(line 52) (req.send(null)). If I do "resend", the response is shown by FIREBUG..

Comment: You're not trying to do cross-domain and therefore running into the same origin policy, are you?

Comment: I don't know nothing about same origin problem...
the URL used in GET is: http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt:8080/TabuWeb/rest/register?nick=ola&key=mundo
My page URL is:
file:///home/carlos/public_html/TabuWeb2/WebContent/index.html?nick=ola&key=mundo

Is there any problem abou same origin policy??Thanks

Comment: This is the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). `http://dcc.fc.up.pt` is a different domain name and protocol to `file://`, which [has it's own special case scenarios](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs) although these can vary cross-browser. Put simply, unless you change your browser's security settings this request will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons why it's not working, and it's hard to tell just from the ajax call.

First, to see your data you should use:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Or directly, to check if ajax returns valid json:

```
alert(req.responseText);
```

data is an object, so `alert(data)` won't show much.

Also, is your url in the same domain as your current page? If not, you might be victim of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Well, I got 0 after doing an alert(req.status): 
So, why req.status=0? I discovered other thing, i started a console.log(req), and I got "GET:"URL" (LOADING)" pointing to server.js(line 52) (req.send(null)). If I do "resend", the response is shown by FIREBUG..
 

Well, I get this after doing an alert(req.status):

else if (req.status != 200){
alert(req.status) ------>>>>>0 return;}

So, why req.status=0? I discovered other thing, i started a console.log(req), and I got "GET:"URL" (LOADING)" pointing to server.js(line 52) (req.send(null)). If I do "resend", the response is shown by FIREBUG..

Comment: I don't know nothing about same origin problem...
the URL used in GET is: http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt:8080/TabuWeb/rest/register?nick=ola&key=mundo
My page URL is:
file:///home/carlos/public_html/TabuWeb2/WebContent/index.html?nick=ola&key=mundo

Is there any problem abou same origin policy??Thanks

Comment: @CarlosPiedade The same origin policy states that you can only get dcc.fc.up.pt:8080 from a page that belongs to dcc.fc.up.pt:8080. Then there are exceptions, but in your case this is the issue. This is a wide subject, difficult to summarize in a forum reply, and I encourage you to search the Web to learn more about it and the workarounds (trusted server, CORS, JSONP).

Comment: thanks, I'll talk with my teacher to see if he knows what is wrong. It's hard to solve this .